# Stop SQL Server - using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I use C# to stop SQL Server?

Answer (score 11):

From http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/

```
public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Stop();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 - this has the advantage that you know whether it worked or not, and when

Answer (score 5):

Execute from a SqlCommand: [`SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188767.aspx). The advantages over the other proposed solutions:

- this requires DB priviledges (sysadmin/serveradmin), not [OS privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28VS.85%29.aspx#access_rights_for_a_service)
- works over any network firewall as long as T-SQL is let in (no [extra ports needed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017))
- you don't need to figure out the service name (MSSQL$instancename)
- works if the service is started from console (`sqlservr -c`, not service start)

Answer (score 3):

Try stopping the service.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

...

```
ServiceController controller  = new ServiceController();

controller.MachineName = ".";
controller.ServiceName = "MySqlServerInstance";


controller.Stop();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
Process.Start("net stop mssqlserver")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `ServiceController` you can kill `sqlservr` process to kill the right process.

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "sqlservr").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Kill());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static bool StopProcess(string name)
{
    try
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcesses().SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == name);
        process.WaitForExit(); 
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //throw;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think unexpected `Kill` is not a great idea for SQL Server integrity. Are you sure you would do it this way?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: if TerminateProcess triggered data corruption SQL Server would be out of business. This is why (almost) all RDBMSs use WAL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259.aspx Torn page protection additionally protects against power outages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337560.aspx

Comment: @Remus, you are right but I still would not choose this method when clean service stop is available

Comment: @SteveTownsend it has been edited to use `WaitForExit()`. I guess that should be a more pleasant halt.

Comment: SingleOrDefault not found in c# ! is t require another using ?